# argparse option with no space

Tags: python, argparse

How can I use argparse to parse an option such as `-DFOO=BAR`, where the "option" here is actually `-D`, and I want it to store `FOO=BAR` as the value?  Do I have to manually handle the unknown args and then look for these myself, or is there an easier way?

Comment: So have you tried this?  Show the code and results.  `argparse` does not have a builtin mechanism for handling generic key:value pairs.  You get to handle anything extra yourself!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, but why do you need that kind of option?